# C# Invalid Uri at Windows phone8. image Uri System.InvalidOperationExeption.

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps

The image file is in the assets folder of my app. I have used the full uri with no success. I try to add it dynamically to my map. The rest of the code works (tested) and I get this error when it tries to get the image from the uri.

```
Image pin = new Image();
 var uri = new Uri(@"/Assets/shop.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    pin.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
 pin.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
        pin.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Marker_Click);
        pin.Height = 20;
        pin.Width = 20;
        pin.Opacity = 50;
        // Create a MapOverlay and add marker.
        MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
        overlay.Content = pin;
        overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
        overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
        mapLayer.Add(overlay);
```

Comment: Did you try UriKind.Relative?

Comment: Yes. Tried relative, absolute with the full path uri as well.

Comment: Strange, have the similar code in my app and it works. Maybe try "Assets/shop.png" and check if your image has Build Action set to Content (right click -> properties)

Comment: The build action was set to Content. Tried it but still got the same exception. It should be working, obviously I am doing something wrong but don't know what.

Comment: Change Copy to output settings in image properties to either "If newer" or "always"

Comment: Still not working.tried both. the pin.Source value is still {System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage}.don't know if that helps. It should show the uri right?

Comment: Oh, I thought that it was the line with new Uri that throws exception. Yeah, BitmapImage should display its Uri source. Do you have Assets in a separate project or it is subfolder?

Comment: I thought for Windows Store Apps you had to do something like `ms-appx:///Assets/shop.png"`.

Comment: It's not windows store app it's windows phone, and yes you do have to do that if you add it in the xaml. C# doesn't need the ms prefix. Assets is the default subfolder for well, assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Image imgPushpin = new Image();
                        imgPushpin.Height = 60;
                        imgPushpin.Width = 41;
                        imgPushpin.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Images/PropertyLocator/imgPropertyPoint.png", UriKind.Relative));
                        imgPushpin.Tag = "Location";
                        imgPushpin.MouseLeftButtonUp += imgPushpinMouseLeftButtonUp;
                        // Create a MapOverlay and add marker
                        MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
                        overlay.Content = imgPushpin;
                        overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(listView[j].latitude, listView[j].longnitude);
                        overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 1);
                        locationLayer = new MapLayer();
                        locationLayer.Add(overlay);
                        mapPropertyLocator.Layers.Add(locationLayer);
                        mapPropertyLocator.ZoomLevel = 11.5;
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! If it's not much of a trouble do you mind telling what was I doing wrong?